# Retrieve a value from an action triggered when a JButton is clicked

Tags: java, asynchronous, jframe, action, return-value

I have a jButton in a jFrame linked to a class extending AbstractAction

```
//Code from myMainFrame.java
CustomAbstractAction abstractAction1 = new CustomAbstractAction();
JButton jButton1 = new JButton();
...
jButton1.setAction(abstractAction1);
```

This abstract action calls a custom jDialog and retrieves an object from it :

```
//Code from CustomAbstractAction.java
private Object myObject = null;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    CustomDialog dial = new CustomDialog ();
    myObject = dial.showDialog();
}

public Object getMyObject()
{
    return myObject;
}
```

So far, everything works fine, I do retreive the correct value in "myObject", and I can get this value with the getter method.

The problem is to know when to call it in myMainFrame : is there a way for myMainFrame to trigger a function the moment my CustomAbstractAction is done with actionPerformed?
Something like

```
//This doesn't work, but should illustrate what I'm trying to do
abstractAction1.onActionPerformed(function {/*Do stuff*/});
```

Comment: You should simply call what you want to call from the action's actionPerformed() method itself.

Comment: Hmmm, since I had to call my function from myMainFrame, I've had to give a reference to myMainFrame in CustomAbstractAction (wich I don't like this much), but it does work this way, thanks :)